# How to create Fibre Channel Data storage on HPE?

Tags: fibre-channel

We bought HPE ML30 with OS Windows Server 2019 that runs on SSD and 4 SATA of 8TB each  (which are not in RAID system, so each disc works on each on). We also added Fibre Channel adapter on server and connected it to our Fibre Channel switch, which is already connected to our Data storage system (that FC is already configured).

My question is, how can I configure this server so I can share data storages through FC switch, so every server connected to FC switch can see this data storage?

Comment: You could do this with Windows and iSCSI, but you've already got FC hardware. Looks like you might want to check out Linux for your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I configure this server so I can share data storages through
> FC switch

You can't, Windows Server has never had the option to be an FC Target/Server, only an Initiator/Client.

There are a number of storage-specific Linux-based appliance operating systems that can do this but not Windows.